# 3 column layout with Floats not changing to one column with Media Query in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-float

I have included Bootstrap 4 into my project but am also utilizing my own custom css. I have a price sheet that shows three price options in the middle of the screen. I am using floats and clears. I want the columns to collapse at 962px. It is not collapsing to 100% until it reaches around 500px. It looks like it is using its own breakpoints. So my question is if any one has dealt with something similar. Thank you in advance. Images and code below.

index.html (yes I have included the meta tag for viewport etc.)

```
<div class="wrapper-red store-backdrop">
        <div class="container-fluid mb-5">
            <h2 class="pt-5 nuestros-clientes text-center">ELIJE EL MEJOR PLAN</h2>
            <div class="text-center">
                <i class="fa fa-2x fa-star text-white" aria-hidden="true"></i>

            </div>
            <div class="container p-4">
                <p class="pt-3 light text-white">Tenemos planes que se ajustan a tus necesidades. ¡Prueba uno y si te
                    agrada, puedes escalar a los demás!
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column2">
                        <div class="bg-white shadow rounded p-3 mt-4 text-center">
                            <h4 class="pt-1">Clase Grupal</h4>
                            <h1><span style="font-size: 80px;font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;">$50</span>
                            </h1>
                            <p>Mensuales</p>
                            <hr>
                            <p>2 clases de 1 hora por semana</p>
                            <p>6 Alumnos Máximo por Clase</p>
                            <p>Maestro Nativo
                            </p>
                            <p>Clases Conversacionales
                            </p>
                            <p>Inicio de clases cada 1er día hábil del mes</p>
                            <p>Sujeto a disponibilidad</p>
                            <p>Horario fijo</p>
                            <div class="button-holder mb-4">
                                <button type="button" class="btn .btn-lg bg-grey btn-outline-secondary mt-5 p-3"><span
                                        style="font-size: 20px;">¡Inscríbete hoy!</span></button>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="column2 middle">
                        <div class="text-center bg-white shadow rounded p-3" style="height: 830px;">
                            <h4 class="pt-1">Clase Individual</h4>
                            <h1><span style="font-size: 80px;font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;">$130</span>
                            </h1>
                            <p>Mensuales</p>
                            <hr>
                            <p>2 clases de 1 hora por semana</p>
                            <p>Clases Uno a Uno (Particulares) </p>
                            <p>Maestro Nativo</p>
                            <p>Clases con Método y Nivel</p>
                            <p>Horario Fijo</p>
                            <p class="mb-5 pb-5">Inicio de clases cada 15 días</p>
                            <div class="button-holder mt-5 mb-5">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg bg-grey btn-danger mt-5 p-3"><span
                                        style="font-size: 20px;">¡Inicia tus clases ya!</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="column2">
                        <div class="text-center bg-white shadow rounded p-3 mt-4">
                            <h4 class="pt-1">Clase Premier</h4>
                            <h1><span style="font-size: 80px;font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;">$300</span>
                            </h1>
                            <p>Mensuales</p>
                            <hr>
                            <p>3 clases de 1 hora por semana
                            </p>
                            <p>Clases Uno a Uno (Particulares) </p>
                            <p>Maestro Nativo</p>
                            <p>Clases Conversacionales o por Nivel
                            </p>
                            <p>Inicio de clases inmediato</p>
                            <p>Horario flexible</p><br><br>
                            <div class="button-holder mb-4">
                                <button type="button" class="btn .btn-lg bg-grey btn-outline-secondary mt-5 p-3"><span
                                        style="font-size: 20px;">¡Avanza hoy!</span></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

style.css

```
.store-backdrop {
  background-image: url(../assets/img/backdropFull.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  width: 100%;
}


.column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.row2:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.middle {
  z-index: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 962px) {
  .column2 {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

[image: pricesheet image]

Essentially, I am looking to change the 3 column layout to individual items stacked at 962px. Again, thank you for you help on this. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I check your code in the browser. It works!

```css
.store-backdrop {
  background-image: url(../assets/img/backdropFull.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  width: 100%;
}


.column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.row2:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.middle {
  z-index: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 962px) {
  .column2 {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  
  <div class="wrapper-red store-backdrop">
        <div class="container-fluid mb-5">
            <h2 class="pt-5 nuestros-clientes text-center">ELIJE EL MEJOR PLAN</h2>
            <div class="text-center">
                <i class="fa fa-2x fa-star text-white" aria-hidden="true"></i>

            </div>
            <div class="container p-4">
                <p class="pt-3 light text-white">Tenemos planes que se ajustan a tus necesidades. ¡Prueba uno y si te
                    agrada, puedes escalar a los demás!
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column2">
                        <div class="bg-white shadow rounded p-3 mt-4 text-center">
                            <h4 class="pt-1">Clase Grupal</h4>
                            <h1><span style="font-size: 80px;font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;">$50</span>
                            </h1>
                            <p>Mensuales</p>
                            <hr>
                            <p>2 clases de 1 hora por semana</p>
                            <p>6 Alumnos Máximo por Clase</p>
                            <p>Maestro Nativo
                            </p>
                            <p>Clases Conversacionales
                            </p>
                            <p>Inicio de clases cada 1er día hábil del mes</p>
                            <p>Sujeto a disponibilidad</p>
                            <p>Horario fijo</p>
                            <div class="button-holder mb-4">
                                <button type="button" class="btn .btn-lg bg-grey btn-outline-secondary mt-5 p-3"><span
                                        style="font-size: 20px;">¡Inscríbete hoy!</span></button>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="column2 middle">
                        <div class="text-center bg-white shadow rounded p-3" style="height: 830px;">
                            <h4 class="pt-1">Clase Individual</h4>
                            <h1><span style="font-size: 80px;font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;">$130</span>
                            </h1>
                            <p>Mensuales</p>
                            <hr>
                            <p>2 clases de 1 hora por semana</p>
                            <p>Clases Uno a Uno (Particulares) </p>
                            <p>Maestro Nativo</p>
                            <p>Clases con Método y Nivel</p>
                            <p>Horario Fijo</p>
                            <p class="mb-5 pb-5">Inicio de clases cada 15 días</p>
                            <div class="button-holder mt-5 mb-5">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg bg-grey btn-danger mt-5 p-3"><span
                                        style="font-size: 20px;">¡Inicia tus clases ya!</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="column2">
                        <div class="text-center bg-white shadow rounded p-3 mt-4">
                            <h4 class="pt-1">Clase Premier</h4>
                            <h1><span style="font-size: 80px;font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;">$300</span>
                            </h1>
                            <p>Mensuales</p>
                            <hr>
                            <p>3 clases de 1 hora por semana
                            </p>
                            <p>Clases Uno a Uno (Particulares) </p>
                            <p>Maestro Nativo</p>
                            <p>Clases Conversacionales o por Nivel
                            </p>
                            <p>Inicio de clases inmediato</p>
                            <p>Horario flexible</p><br><br>
                            <div class="button-holder mb-4">
                                <button type="button" class="btn .btn-lg bg-grey btn-outline-secondary mt-5 p-3"><span
                                        style="font-size: 20px;">¡Avanza hoy!</span></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Mina. Thank you for your response. May I ask what browser you are using? That might help me narrow down why it is not working for me. In responsive, when I adjust my width, the items squish together at 962px and under until they get to 500px, then they go to a single column which is the type of behaviour I am trying to avoid. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the code by removing the bootstrap margins from the elements and changing my css to the following:

```
.store-backdrop {
  background-image: url(../assets/img/backdropFull.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  width: 100%!important;
}


.column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.price {
  width: 385px;
}

.row2:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.first,
.last {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.middle {
  z-index: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .column2 {
    width: 100%!important;
    float: none!important;
  }
  .price {
    width: 500px!important;
    margin: 0 auto!important;
  }
  .center,
  .last {
    margin-top: 30px!important;
  }
}
```

I hope this helps anyone else struggling with the same issue. Cheers.